# How to prove $n(T)=\sup\{|\langle Tx,x \rangle |, \|x\|=1\}$ is a norm on $B(H)$ and $n(T)\lt\|T\|\lt2n(T)$ where $T\in B(H)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space over $\mathbb C$. If $T\in B(H)$, how to prove that

$$n(T)=\sup\{|\langle Tx,x \rangle |, \|x\|=1\}$$ is a norm on $B(H)$ and $$n(T)\lt||T||\lt2n(T)\ \textrm{?}$$
I couldn't show that $\|T\|\lt2n(T)$.

Thanks for any hint

Comment: All I can say off the top of my head is that we must somehow use the fact that $H$ is not $2$-dimensional, for in $2$ dimensions a rotation $T$ thru $90^o$ has $\|T\|=1$ and $n(T)=0.$

Comment: @user254665 : That won't happen if $H$ is complex.

Comment: I am pretty sure those inequalities should be $\leqslant$ instead of $<$. See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2281150/161825